# bash script read user input and export it as variable

Tags: bash, shell, openssl, csr

I am trying to make a script to generate csr file via openssl. I want to prompt user to provide additional alt_names. Openssl.cnf is static 
and can't do much inside. It is ok if user needs 1 SAN 
so I can export it via system variables.

```
[alt_names] 
DNS.1=${ENV::SAN}
```

If I need more SANs then syntax under config looks like:

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1=test.example.com
DNS.2=www.example.com
IP.1=1.1.1.1
IP.2-1.1.2.2
```

So, I couldn't find any other example how to automate it expect of openssl command it self and paste this into cli like this :

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:www.exmple.com,DNS:test.example.com,IP:1.1.1.1") -days 365
```

I was thinking to use a read function in shell to prompt user to provide his DNS:xxxxxx or IP:xxxx entires until user press [enter] 
I found some examples but can't figure it out how to export it into openssl command.

One of the example I found is :

```
    array=()
while IFS= read -r -p "Next item (end with an empty line): " line; do
    [[ $line ]] || break  # break if line is empty
    array+=("$line")
done

printf '%s
' "Items read:"
printf '  «%s»
' "${array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think i have sorted this out... 
I used above example with read function and array, this is exactly what i wanted to achieve here.

```
"openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=${array[@]}") -days 365 "
```

If anyone has got a better solution feel free to submit it here.

Thanks

Piotr